# Response time is high in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am sending 100 user requests in JMeter. It is taking more than 10 minutes to respond. At the same time, when I sending request from browser the server taking only 5 seconds to respond.

Why is the response time in JMeter higher than the browser time?

Comment: Can you please post your test plan design? Have you added the ramp up and appropriate timers in your test plan.

Comment: yes i have added ramp up time in my test plan

Answer (score 1):

If single request takes around 5 seconds it is quite expected that 100 requests take 500 seconds if you run them sequentially.

If you run them in parallel - consider the following troubleshooting tecnhiques

- Run your test with 1-2 virtual users / iterations with [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) enabled to ensure that it is doing what it is supposed to be doing
- Once you verify your test integrity define the load pattern (how many users will be used for test, ramp-up and ramp-down periods, time to hold the load, etc.). If you are new to JMeter you may find [Ultimate Thread Group](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420305-How-To-Configure-Ultimate-Stepping-Thread-Groups-Scenario) more convenient to use than normal [JMeter Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). You can install custom Thread Groups using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
- Make sure you are following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- Make sure to monitor the health of your application under test (and JMeter load generator(s)) via either built-in OS performance monitoring tools or using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

Comment: Is it meaningful to use one credentials to test multiple users?